# xsl:copy-of external file without doctype, posible?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have the html files that I can't modify with latin characters:

```
<root>
        <h1>
                Actividades acu&aacute;ticas
        </h1>
        <p>
                Actividades acu&aacute;ticas
        </p>
</root>
```

and I want to load nodes from an XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document('content.html')/root/p/node()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following error:

> The entity "aacute" was referenced, but not declared.'

I only get it to work if I add the DOCTYPE to the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<root>
        <h1>
                Actividades acu&aacute;ticas
        </h1>
        <p>
                Actividades acu&aacute;ticas
        </p>
</root>
```

Is there a way to do it **without modifying** the HTML?

Comment: Are you tied to XSLT 1? Can you use another XSLT processor, perhaps 2 or 3 capable, so that you could run David Carlisle's XSLT 2.0 implementation of an HTML tag soup parser that would existing HTML entities?

Comment: I am tied to XSLT 1.0

Comment: On what platform, which XSLT processor? Some XSLT 1.0 processors (e.g. libxslt) also support HTML parsing, depending on the platform (e.g. Python, PHP) there might be API methods like loadHTML you can use to parse HTML in an input tree usable from XSLT/XPath.

Answer (score 0):

Using an XSLT 2 or 3 processor (like Saxon 9 or 10 or 11, like SaxonJS 2 or like any AltovaXML version since 2015, I think) you could import David Carlisle's HTML tag soup parser implementation in XSLT 2 and use it e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:dcp="data:,dpc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="dcp:htmlparse(unparsed-text('content.html'), '', true())/root/p/node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```